# set containerLayout in android

Tags: java, android

I want use this library into my project : [Library](https://github.com/carlonzo/StikkyHeader)

My problem is how to enter the containerLayout, I got this code :

```
StikkyHeaderBuilder.stickTo(mListView)
    .setHeader(R.id.header, containerLayout)
    .minHeightHeader(250)
    .build();`
```

my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="230dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/main_header" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="G Vision"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I saw a demo of the source, but the fragment used in the demo, and I want to use my activity.

How I should fill the container layer?

Comment: container layout will be the parent layout in which your mListview resides. may be LinearLayout or Relative layout. share your xml layout code.

Comment: @QadirHussain, xml code has shared. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set id for the most outer RelaytiveLayout.

in your activity make object

```
RelativeLayout containerLayout = (RelaytiveLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_id);
```

then put this in here

```
StikkyHeaderBuilder.stickTo(mListView)
.setHeader(R.id.header, containerLayout)
.minHeightHeader(250)
.build();
```

Comment: tnx, but when running show this error :   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tellfa.clashplus/com.tellfa.clashplus.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.widget.ListView.getContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: may be library is not loaded successfully. try to clean and run again

Comment: I do this time, but it did not work. i must really need this library. please test this lib in your PC and your android project. tnx

Comment: Dear @QadirHussain, do you test it ?

Comment: fix it, tnx my dear friend <3